# Как можно сменить версию Junit

Tags: java, junit

Весь вопрос заключается в том, как изменить версию Junit? Когда начал писать тесты, то IDEA спрашивала какой хочу использовать. Отметил на тот момент JUnit4, но хочу 5 версию попробовать. Верно понимаю, что мне для этого нужно просто аннотации поменять, которые используются в 5 версии и всё? Больше никаких действий не требуется. В Pom.xml у меня такие зависимости:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Добавьте зависимости в pom

Comment: Добавил, а с остальными зависимости всё корректно? Ничего удалить не нужно, если я обновил на junit5? https://github.com/Blacit/HomeRent/blob/master/pom.xml Можно ещё как-то в IDEA проверить то, какую версию junit использую?

Comment: @Blacit spring-boot-starter-test точно нужно, остальные вроде добавляют какие то библиотеки для доп функций. Ставите курсор на класс, alt+enter - > create test, после чего выбираете junit 5

Comment: Навёл курсор на класс, где уже есть тесты, нажал alt+enter, мне предложил только это: Create subclass, сделать класс приватным, add javadoc. Класс у меня помечен, что для тестирования `@SpringBootTest
public class HouseTest {`

Comment: @Blacit не на тот где есть тесты, а на класс в проекте, к которому надо сделать тест

Comment: Нашёл, спасибо.